# How to set the file.encoding property at exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, utf, exec-maven-plugin

I trying to exec my standalone application via exec-maven-plugin, but it started with WIN encoding, not UTF-8. I read about Java command line key -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. How to set this property to my application?
Thanx.

maven pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
```

Comment: command line is:    mvn exec:java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the exec-maven-plugin documentation, it should look like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
            <commandlineArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</commandlineArgs>
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

To set encoding for `mvn exec:java`, set `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable, e.g.:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Here is what [exec-maven-plugin usage](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) page says:

> Note: The java goal doesn't spawn a new process. Any VM specific option that you want to pass to the executed class must be passed to the Maven VM using the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. E.g.
>
> MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
>
> Otherwise consider using the exec goal.

Answer (score 1):

more direct method than Todd's (his one's still cool though):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <key>file.encoding</key>
                <value>UTF-8</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>                
</plugin>
```

samples [here](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).